# awsのREST リクエストの署名(verstion 2)と認証について

Tags: javascript, aws, amazon-s3

現在webサービスのフォーム値をawsのs3に保存しようとしているのですが，v2認証がうまくいきません．

awsの[ドキュメント](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html)では以下の手順で署名を作成するように記述されています．

```
Authorization = "AWS" + " " + AWSAccessKeyId + ":" + Signature;

Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) );

StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Date + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;

CanonicalizedResource = [ "/" + Bucket ] +
    <HTTP-Request-URI, from the protocol name up to the query string> +
    [ subresource, if present. For example "?acl", "?location", "?logging", or "?torrent"];

CanonicalizedAmzHeaders = <described below>
```

そして同ページで以下のようなサンプルがかかれています．

```
-----------------request--------------------------------
GET /photos/puppy.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000

Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:
bWq2s1WEIj+Ydj0vQ697zp+IXMU=

--------------------stringToSign-----------------------
GET\n
\n
\n
Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000\n
/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg
```

これらのサンプルを元に署名処理を書きました．
具体的には以下のようにかきました．

````
```
var accessKey = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE'
var secretKey = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
var stringToSign = `
GET\n
\n
\n
Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000\n
/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg
`
//UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign )
var enStringToSign = encodeURI(stringToSign);
//HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign )
var hmacSha1 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(secretKey, enStringToSign);
//Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) );
var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hmacSha1);
var authorization = `AWS ${accessKey}:${signature}`;
console.log(authorization)
//"AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:KXQrJvmB8Mr4qb6x5wVxcgEdBM8="
```
````

sample通り

````
```
AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:
bWq2s1WEIj+Ydj0vQ697zp+IXMU=
```
````

と出力されません．
どこが悪いかわかる方教えていただけると助かります

### 環境

- os
  windows
- 言語
  javascript
- ライブラリ
  [crypto.js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず明らかにおかしいのは、この擬似コードを:

```
StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Date + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;
```

こうなおしてしまっているところです。

```
var stringToSign = `
GET\n
\n
\n
Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000\n
/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg
`
```

JavaScriptのバッククオート(Template literal)は、ソースコード上の全ての改行を(`\n`にして)保持するので、上記のコードではあちこちに余分な改行が入ってしまいます。例えば以下のようにする必要があるでしょう。

```
var stringToSign = `GET


Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000
/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg`
```

また、あなたのこの行:

```
var enStringToSign = encodeURI(stringToSign);
```

これに相当する行は、擬似コードのどこにもありません。`UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign )`をどうするのか迷われたのでしょうが、この擬似コードは文字列をUTF-8表現のバイト列に変換することを表していて、その処理はCryptoJSに文字列を渡すことで自動的にやってくれます。

で、最後の1個がここ。

```
var hmacSha1 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(secretKey, enStringToSign);
```

秘密鍵と変換対象のメッセージが逆転しています。つい擬似コードの`HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) )`の順番にひきずられたのでしょうが、正しくはこちら。

```
var hmacSha1 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(stringToSign, secretKey);
```

(上記したように`enStringToSign`は要らないので`stringToSign`に変えてあります。)

---

全部つなげると、こんな感じでしょうか。

```
var accessKey = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE';
var secretKey = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY';
var stringToSign = `GET


Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000
/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg`;
//HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign )
var hmacSha1 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(stringToSign, secretKey);
//Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) );
var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hmacSha1);
var authorization = `AWS ${accessKey}:${signature}`;
console.log(authorization)
```

お試しに際は、一文字でも間違えると同じ結果になりませんので、ご注意ください。